# How to fix "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error"

Tags: .net, iis, web-applications, web-config

OK, after spending 2 days trying to fix this with no luck i decided to post this question, maybe someone can help me fix it.

I have 2 Servers both using Window 2019

The first been running for a year with no issues.

Now I have a new server and I want to run the website that is on server 1 on server 2

The webapp works perfectly on server 1

I copied everything into server 2 and I think I installed all needed to server 2

but when I run the webapp on server 2 I get this error

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\D:\__Web\CD\web.config
Requested URL      http://ns5*****3.ip-***-***-***.net:591/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0: 

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
View more information »
```

I checked almost all questions in Stakoverflow that talk about this error with no luck

Here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
<!--
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" maxUrl="10241" maxQueryString="20481" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DeepMed.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: e306e167-c5cb-470b-a55e-60843f143b05-->
```

when i try to open "Directory Browsing" I get this error

[image]

I gave full permission to iusr and iis_iusrs

I reinstalled rewrite.

**FYI: I have Web APIs that works fine on the 2nd server and I can see the "Directory Browsing" of it.**

Edit:
Here is the directory as requested

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the root directory structure of your site? including the path. Seems to me that IIS is struggling with the path.

Comment: @Alex i posted that, not sure if it is what you want

Comment: Ok, just looking at the directory that IIS is trying to look in: "\\?\D:\" which clearly looks problematic. Is there some sort of path rewrite going on?

Comment: Can you create a new directory and start over?

Comment: @Alex i did, i deleted everything and started from scratch, same results

Comment: Ok, well it sounds to me like the path \\?\D:\__Web needs to be resolved...are you using the D: drive on your other server? Is it possible to have the site on your C: drive?

Comment: @Alex yes i just tried it, still getting the same error

Comment: So you now get a \\?\C:\__Web\CD\web.config error? Even in the directory browsing with IIS? very strange.

Comment: @Alex yes i am getting the same error

Comment: What is the physical path when you click 'Basic Settings' for the site node?

Comment: @Alex D:\\__Web\CD

Comment: I wonder if IIS is getting confused with \__ my last suggestion is to get rid of the __ and just have D:\Web

Comment: @Alex i tried without the __ still same error

Comment: ...don't you just hate this job sometimes?! I tried to replicate the set up that you have locally in IIS, but I have not encountered any issues. Without knowing the rest of your setup, user permissions etc. it's difficult to suggest what to do next.

Comment: Classic ASP.NET Core module missing error. A report can tell you more common issues in this field, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: @Alex BTW, I noticed that you were willing to help, but you do need to be familiar with IIS error page and pay attention to the error code pattern. This issue is well known, so using “IIS”, “ASP.NET Core”, “500.19” and the error code together a search engine can quickly take you to the right direction. Issues caused by file system usually trigger other error codes.

Comment: @LexLi I see…the path issue is likely a red herring then.